# AngularJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token s

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, http

I have a function called login, when the User pushes the button, the code below will be executed.

So i try to see if the user exists and to get his data in an JSON Object but that doesn't work, i get following Message:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
    at Object.parse (native)
```

the URL is exactly like i want it to be.

```
$scope.login = function() {
    var request = $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "/REST/user" + "/" + $scope.email + "/" + "password" + "/" + $scope.password,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : "application/json"
        }
        });

    request.success(function(response) {
        location.href = "../views/test.html"
    });
    request.error(function(response) {
        growl.addErrorMessage("doesn't work", {
            ttl : 4000
        });
    });
}
```

Output by Browser

```
{
"id": "9be1804a-e366-11e4-9d4b-82ea0d805d53",
"email": "test@gmx.com",
"facebook_id": null,
"firstname": "test",
"lastname": "blabla",
"password": null,
"gender": null,
"is_active": "0",
"birthday": null
}
```

Comment: You might want to include the output of the REST url if you visit it from the browser

Comment: You can use the $http.get("/REST/user" + "/" + $scope.email + "/" + "password" + "/" + $scope.password) syntax to simplify your request.

Comment: Hey Jake, i already tried, but same message.

Comment: you tried without the headers?

Comment: yes but the effect is the same

Comment: can you add a console.log of this: "/REST/user" + "/" + $scope.email + "/" + "password" + "/" + $scope.password  before performing the request? Just to make sure you are hitting the right page.

Comment: Hello can you provide  a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to `JSON.parse` throwing an error when it encounters an object with key that doesn't start with quotes `"`.

For example:

```
{ abc: 123 }
```

would throw "Unexpected token a".

`$http`, by default, treats any data in response with `"Content-Type": "application/json"` or anything that starts with `{` or `[` as JSON, and invokes `JSON.parse`.

Take a look at the response in the Network tab of the developer console to see what may have triggered it.

Comment: same thing happened to me when the api I called throw error message, the http expects a valid json in return.